# Обрезать сохранены url ссылки python

Tags: python, парсер

я отрезал (www. и .ru .com .rf), можно ли как то укоротить и упростить?

```
    soup = BS(driver.page_source,'lxml')
orgs = soup.findAll('div', class_='g')
for org in orgs:#на страничках добавляем данные(Заголовок, ссылка)
    name = org.find('h3',class_='LC20lb MBeuO DKV0Md').text.strip('...') # поиск заголовков
    link = org.find('div',class_='yuRUbf').find('a').get('href')#поиск ссылок
    if "http" in str(link) or "www" in str(link):
        parsed = tldextract.extract(link)
        parsed = ".".join([i for i in parsed if i])
        if 'www.' in parsed:
            if '.ru' in parsed:
                print(parsed[4:-3])
            elif '.com' in parsed:
                print(parsed[4:-4])
        else:
            if '.ru' in parsed:
                print(parsed[:-3])
            elif '.rt.com' in parsed:
                print(parsed[:-7])
            elif '.com' in parsed:
                print(parsed[:-4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот кусок кода из учебного проекта, может пригодится чем-то. Обрезает все лишнее из разных url.

```
data = {"Website":""}
url = 'https://www.dropcontact.com/'

print('url компании : ',url)

if 'www.' in url :

    index = url.find('.')

    new_url = url[index + 1:]

    if new_url.endswith('/'):
        new_url = new_url.replace('/', '')
        data["Website"]= new_url

    else:
        data["Website"] = new_url


if not 'www.'in url and url.endswith('/'):
    url = url[:-1]
    data["Website"] = url


if not 'www.' in url and not url.endswith('/') and not 'https://' in url and not 'http://' in url:
    data["Website"] = url


if 'https://' in url and not 'www' in url or 'http://' in url and not 'www' in url:
    index = url.find('//')
    new_url = url[index + 2:]

    if new_url.endswith('/'):
        new_url = new_url.replace('/', '')
        data["Website"] = new_url

    else:
        data["Website"] = new_url

print('*',data)
```